# gl_MultiTexCoord in HLSL/CG?

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, shader, cg

I cam currently trying to convert a GLSL shader into a CG shader for Unity. I am an absolute beginner regarding shaders, so please bear with me.

While doing so, I encountered the following in the GLSL shader:

```
oBentNormal = gl_MultiTexCoord7;
```

From my understanding, `gl_MultiTexCoord7` is a Color of a Multi-Texture at a specific Coordinate. Or something? Not really sure.

My question is, is there an equivalent for CG? How can I access those Multi-Texture Coordinates in CG with Unity? The Semantics in the Unity Documentation only speak of TextureCoord, and they only go from 0 to 3. (i.e. `TEXCOORD0`, `TEXCOORD1`, `TEXCOORD2`, `TEXCOORD3`)

Answer (score 0):

`TEXCOORD{4,5,6,7}` are available on some Cg profile, see :

See http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/vs_2_0.html

Do you know which profile you have to target ?